# Conditional formatting in non contiguous range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have data in collumns to wich I want to apply conditional formatting (ex: E, K and X).
For each row I want to highlight the minimum value (or values) that is greater than zero. How to do this with a formula or VBA?

I'm not having success with most solutions online, thanks for your time :)

Comment: are you trying to highlight the lowest value as long as it is ubove zero or every value that is over zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select column E and apply this conditional format formula:

```
=AND(E1>0,E1=MIN(IF($E1>0,$E1,2^999),IF($K1>0,$K1,2^999),IF($X1>0,$X1,2^999)))
```

Then copy column E and select column K, right-click -> paste special -> Formats
Repeat for column X

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula for E1

`=AND(E1>0,OR(K1<=0,E1<=K1),OR(X1<=0,E1<=X1))`

set up columns K and X using the same logic

Comment: What if E2 = 2, K2 = 0, and X2 = 4? Ignoring 0's, the lowest value is E2 at 2, but this formula would not flag it as such.

Comment: Yes you are right - I changed the formula so that it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1, for example, put the following formula (if you are trying to calculate for column E):

```
=MIN(E:E)
```

This will put the smallest value in column E in cell A1.  Then put in conditional formula by say:

```
=IF(E1=$A$1,1,0)
```

This tells the cell that if its value is equal to A1 then true.   Within the conditional formatting change the range to column E.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another answer here about applying conditional formatting using the graphical rules manager. You can expand the range of your conditional formatting by separating the ranges that you'd like the formatting to be applied to with a `,`. So if you had a formatting rule that was applied like this:

```
=$V$9:$Z$100
```

You could apply it to another range like this:

```
=$V$9:$Z$100,$AA$22:$AC$354
```

I haven't tried this with named ranges, but I assume that it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can select non-contiguous ranges of cells by clicking in the upper left cell of the first range, hold and drag to the lower right.  Release the mouse, then press and hold the CTRL key while you click and drag to select additional ranges of cells to add to the selection.

You can then open the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager and create a single rule that governs the formatting of all the selected ranges.

But, this may not produce the results you want, because all the selected cells in each row would be formatted the same.

I think you would have to format each column with a separate rule to get ONLY the lowest, non-zero value highlighted in a particular row.